# /etc/samba/smb.conf: With what command's logical approach the octal values are based?: chmod or umask?

Tags: networking, configuration, samba, chmod, umask

About Samba I am reading the following valuable tutorial:

- [How to Set Up a Network Shared Folder on Ubuntu With Samba](https://www.makeuseof.com/set-up-network-shared-folder-ubuntu-with-samba/)

At the `Step 2: Configuring Samba` section appears the following configuration

```bash
[sambashare]
comment= Network Shared Folder by Samba Server on Ubuntu
path = /home/your_username/sambashare
force user = smbuser
force group = smbgroup
create mask = 0664
force create mode = 0664
directory mask = 0775
force directory mode = 0775
public = yes
read only = no
```

Observe that four parameters work with octal values.

Just to avoid to do a disaster about configuration, about those octal values shown: With what command's logical approach are they based?: `chmod` or `umask`?

**Observation** I am doing this question because for these parameters appear the `mask` and `mode` terms within their own names.

Answer (score 0):

The [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/smb.conf) tells you:

```
create mask (S)

   When a file is created, the necessary permissions are calculated
   according to the mapping from DOS modes to UNIX permissions, and
   the resulting UNIX mode is then bit-wise 'AND'ed with this
   parameter.
```

Whereas a `umask` value's 1-bits **clear** the corresponding bits of the file mode, Samba's `create mask` uses its **0-bits** to clear the corresponding bits of the file mode.  Note that `smb.conf` allows `create mode` as a synonym, if you find that clearer to remember.